# How to order when using ToDictionary()

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, ienumerable

I was asked to add an "ALL" item in a ComboBox where this query was assigned as its DataSource, the item "ALL" should be the first one seen in the control

```
        Dim qryEmp = From emp In db.Members.ToList
                        Order By emp.LogonId Ascending
                        Select New GPUserQueryResult With {
                            .LoginId = emp.LogonId,
                            .FullName = GetUserName(emp.LogonId)
                        }
```

The code I ended up using was this:

```
            Dim allUser() As GPUserQueryResult = {New GPUserQueryResult With {.LoginId = -1, .FullName = AllValues}}
            Dim addEmpty As IEnumerable(Of GPUserQueryResult) = allUser

            Dim allRecs As IEnumerable(Of GPUserQueryResult) = addEmpty.Union(qryEmp)

            EmpList = allRecs.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.LoginId, Function(x) x.FullName)
```

At first though I tried this:

```
            Dim allUser() As GPUserQueryResult = {New GPUserQueryResult With {.LoginId = -1, .FullName = AllValues}}
            Dim addEmpty As IEnumerable(Of GPUserQueryResult) = allUser

            Dim allRecs As IEnumerable(Of GPUserQueryResult) = qryEmp.Union(addEmpty)

            EmpList = allRecs.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.LoginId, Function(x) x.FullName)
            EmpList.Keys.OrderBy(Function(x) x)
```

But the "ALL" item was always the last, even though I tried to use the OrderBy method   can someone explain why?  And if this was the best way to acheive the goal

Comment: A dictionary is an _unordered_ collection of key/value pairs.  If you want order, use an [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) or roll out your own.

Comment: I know that the dictionary cannot be ordered, I guess I thought that with the possible OrderBy on the Keys, that it would be able to Order the Key values in the container.

Comment: Using methods such as `OrderBy()` on a collection doesn't modify it, it only creates a view of the collection that when iterated over, is applied.  If you iterated over the results of the `OrderBy()` call, you would then see the "ordered" keys.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code above and the "ALL" item displayed first as expected. Not sure why it's not working on your side. However, another simpler way of doing what you need:

```
Dim qryEmp = .... ' your existing linq to retrieve employees
```

Now you need to insert the "ALL" item to the first position. First convert the `qryEmp` to List object:

```
Dim EmpList = qryEmp.ToList()
```

Insert the "ALL" item at position 0:

```
EmpList.Insert(0, New GPUserQueryResult With {.LoginId = -1, .FullName = AllValues})
```

Bind list to ComboBox:

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "LoginId"
ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(EmpList, Nothing)
```

Sample:

[image]

Comment: I knew how to do it in a List(of T), I was trying to acheive the same thing with the Dictionary, matbe the Dictionary is overkill for just acting like a datasource.